# How to pass timestamp condition in DB2 where clause

Tags: sql, timestamp, db2

Here is my query :

```
Select * from XYZ
WHERE
UPDT_DTTM > 2020-03-09 03:49:18
```

What is the correct way to implement this.?

I am getting SQL error as :

```
SQL Error [42601]: ILLEGAL SYMBOL "3". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.9.78
```

Comment: Date constants should be surrounded by single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select * 
from xyz 
where updt_dttm > timestamp ('2020-03-09 03:49:18')
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=c51e3bcbfa4583153ba55fbc4db4f8c4).